# ConstraintLayout not working for some widgets

Tags: android

I am using the ConstraintLayout but in some devices, it is not working perfectly. All of the widgets are inside ConstraitLayout are working fine but only 1 widget **dashed curve line** can't place at the right place.

This picture from GenyMotion Samsung S2 4.1.1
[image]

And this picture from GenyMotion Nexus5x 6.0.0[image]

**UPDATED**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:background="@drawable/direction_bg"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layerType="software"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:id="@+id/arc"
        android:background="#88000000"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/home_plane_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/home_plane_size"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_plane"
        android:id="@+id/plane"
        android:rotation="-65"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        android:background="#88000000"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/guideline1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/from_point"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/home_point_icon_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/home_point_icon_size"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_radio_button"
        android:id="@+id/from_point"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        android:background="#88000000"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/guideline1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/arc"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/arc"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/home_point_icon_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/home_point_icon_size"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        android:background="#88000000"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_radio_button"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/arc"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/arc"
        android:id="@+id/ep"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/guideline1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline2" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/guideline1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Left side of black rectangle mustbe center of screen.
[image]

Comment: Add your .xml file.

Comment: `"Constrait Layout not working for some widgets"`, some? meaning which one?

Comment: XML file too large for post. That dashed curve line is a `LinearLayout` with one `ImageView`.

Comment: so what do you expect from people if you dont post any code?

Comment: answer updated for .xml file

Comment: It's complete .xml ??? I think it's not complete because as per you give constraint to another id, those id components not found.

Comment: @shweta shorter version of xml file updated. Can you solve this problem?